# Why Jenkins can't push back to git server?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

having in a jenkins pipeline (not multibranch, single pipeline):

```
git url 'ssh://git@xxx.git', credentialsId:'xxxx'
...
sh 'git push --set-upstream origin master'
```

The git command passes, but then after creating a commit and trying to push I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already added key to the git repository, but I can't push data back to the repo. Whats the root cause here?

Answer (score 0):

On your Jenkins slave machine, did you check the permissions for your .ssh folder and for your public/private ssh keys?

More information here:
https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder

If the permissions look good, maybe your ssh key only have a read access on your Git repo?

What tool are using to host your Git repositories?

Comment: According to the bitbucket configuration, the ssh key has read/write permissions currently

Comment: So it's more a ssh folder/files permissions on your Jenkins slave.